# How to make two or more executable channels of JSch synchronized?

Tags: java, networking, ssh, jsch

I have created a ssh session to a remote windows machine using JSch. The windows machine has cygwin installed on it to accept ssh from remote client. To execute the commands i have opened executable channels using the command,

```
Channel channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");
```

I am mapping a shared directory on to the machine from one channel. As the same channel can't be used to run another command, i am using another channel of the same session to retrieve the mapped drives.

But i am not getting the previously mapped drive itself (the one which i mapped earlier in the same code). How to make these two channels synchronized. The code i used is as below

```
Channel channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("net use Y: \\\\\\\\share\\\\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\\\\User password");
channel.connect();

channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("net use");
channel.connect();
```

The output that i got after running is,

```
The command completed successfully.

exit-status: 0
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  Y:        \\share\directory     Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.

exit-status: 0
```

Also i need to execute multiple commands on the mapped directory, based on the previous command output i need to run some more commands on the same mapped directory. I think if the channels are synchronized then the problem running multiple commands will be solved.

```
public void method()
{
    Channel channel = null;
    try
    {
        channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("net use Y: \\\\\\\\share\\\\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\\\\User password");
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true)
        {
            while(in.available()>0)
            {
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel.isClosed())
            {
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    try
    {
        channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("net use");
        channel.connect();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true)
        { 
            while(in.available()>0)
            {
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)
                    break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channel.isClosed())
            {
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
        System.out.println(e.toString());           
    }
}
```

Comment: when not use a `shell` channel

Comment: @ScaryWombat The Shell channel is not intended to be used for automating command execution. And it will also make it difficult to tell, what output comes from, what command.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the first channel to close, before opening another one.

Use the [`Channel.isClosed` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#isClosed--).

Comment: I have even tried that thing. But there is no change in the output.

Comment: will this statement create another session kind of channel or just a channel `channel = client_session.openChannel("exec");`

Comment: Actually, reading your question carefully now: the Y: drive is in the `net use` output. Yes, I see the "Unavailable" status. But are you sure you get different results when executing the two commands immediately after each other in Windows console? Like `net use Y: \\share\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\User password & net use`

Comment: The `openChannel` creates a new virtual channel within the existing SSH connection.

Comment: Yes i have checked it on the Windows console. When i execute both of the commands on the console it gives correct output, ie. the status of mount directory will be OK. But here it is Unavailable.

Comment: Dud did you execute them immediately one after another using the `&` operator?

Comment: yeah, i got correct output  `C:\>net use Y: \\share\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\User password & net use
The command completed successfully.

New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\share\directory     Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.`

Comment: Sow us your code with the `icClosed` (append it into your question).

Comment: output is same as it is in the question.

Comment: If it is the same (no `exit-status:` line), your `isClosed` code is not triggered.

Comment: Let's try with some trivial command, like `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10` - Will your loop wait complete 10 seconds before breaking?

Comment: Yes, the command waits for 10 seconds, it waits till the channel is closed. I think that `client_session.openChannel("exec");` creates a new virtual channel which is similar to a session. But i am not sure about this.

Comment: So your code is correct. What you are experiencing with the `net use`, is some peculiarity of the command. Nothing wrong with your code. Did you try this? `setCommand("net use Y: \\\\\\\\share\\\\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\\\\User password & net use")`?

Comment: yes, i tried that one, but i am not getting output for `net use` part of the command. But when i use `setCommand("net use Y: \\\\\\\\share\\\\directory /USER:WORKGROUP\\\\User password ; net use");`, i will get the mount status as OK.

Comment: Good. So use that.

Comment: Based on the previous command output (which was executed with one of the channels) i need to run some more commands on the same mapped directory. After parsing the output if i open new channel to run more commands. In that channel the drive itself will not be mapped. This is the basic problem behind the question.

Comment: OK, but that's a different question than you have asked. You have asked *"How to make two or more executable channels of JSch synchronized?"* - For that I gave you an answer. Your problem is about a specific behavior of a specific command. That's a new question. I consider this one answered and closed. And you should ask a new question.